# How to (safely) install Windows 10 on a Linux system

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot, grub

I have Linux (Arch) only system with a spare partition that I'd like to use for Windows 10. It's a notebook with UEFI. I remember I had some trouble back then when installing Arch because of UEFI. I think I have it disabled now, but not entirely sure. This is what my disk layout looks like

[image]

`/dev/sda3` (Win8 label) is where I want to install Windows 10. Can anyone advise me on how to do it without wrecking my Linux system? I use GRUB 2 to boot. Thank you

Comment: Virtualise the Windows 10 install using, say, VirtualBox. You'll then be able to boot and run Windows whilst in Arch.

Comment: When you use, say, VirtualBox it won't touch your Arch boot at all so it's safe.  Just so long as your machine can virtualise and has good resources (processor, RAM and HDD space)

Comment: Thanks @BigChris but that solves nothing for me, I need native performance, that's why I have the partition there. I need it for video editing. VirtualBox would really suck. But thank you